# Gradient Descent on Boston Dataset

Tags: numpy, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement the gradient descent algorithm from scratch and use it on the Boston dataset. Here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error


dataset = load_boston()
X = dataset.data
y = dataset.targe

def gradient_descent(X, y, eta = 0.0001, n_iter = 1000):
    '''
    Gradient descent implementation
    eta: Learning Rate
    n_iter: Number of iteration
    '''
    b0 = b1 = 1
    costList = []
    m = len(y)
    for i in range(n_iter):
        error = y - (b0 + X*b1)
        #Updating b0 and b1
        b0 += -eta * (-2 * error.sum() / m )
        b1 += -eta * (-2 * X.dot(error).sum() / m )
        costList.append(mean_squared_error(y, (b0 + b1*X)))
    return costList


listt = gradient_descent(X, y)
```

However, I am receiving the following error when I try to compute **error**: `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (506,) (506,13)` where the shape of y is  `(506,) and shape of y_predict is  (506, 13)` I

**This error happens because the dimension of y_predict is 2 while y is one dimensional. However, I don't know how to overcome this problem.**

**GD works when I only use one feature of the whole dataset; however, I want to use all of them**

Comment: Is this really the code that results in the error message that you quoted? For one thing you misspelled “target”. For another, there is no variable called “y_predict” in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [multivariate linear regression](https://ko.coursera.org/lecture/machine-learning/gradient-descent-for-multiple-variables-Z9DKX) instead of univariate linear regression which you used becase **X** has multiple values in a row.

So, **b1** should be vector, not scalar.

I have just convert your code to multivariate linear regression.
But it easily diverged(**b1** gonna be very large). So, maybe you should consider advanced linear regression like [ridge regression](https://towardsdatascience.com/ridge-regression-for-better-usage-2f19b3a202db).

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error


dataset = load_boston()
X = dataset.data
y = np.expand_dims(dataset.target,axis=1) # for maxtrix mul

#new_X = (X-X.mean())/X.std()

def gradient_descent(X, y, eta = 0.000001, n_iter = 1000):
    '''
    Gradient descent implementation
    eta: Learning Rate
    n_iter: Number of iteration
    '''
    b0 = 1
    b1 = np.ones((13,1)) # b1 should be vector
    costList = []
    m = len(y)
    for _ in range(n_iter):
        # error = y - (b0 + X.dot(b1)) # it is wrong
        error = (b0 + X.dot(b1)) - y

        #Updating b0 and b1
        b0 += -eta * (error.sum() / m )
        b1 += -eta * (X.T.dot(error) / m )
        costList.append(mean_squared_error(y, (b0 + X.dot(b1))))
    return costList


listt = gradient_descent(X, y, eta=10e-5,n_iter=10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, it is wrong. I believe cost should decrease monotonically over the round but it is not in this case

Comment: @EmrahSariboz I have error about sign of error. I just fixed it. And gradient descent method does not guarantee convergence. So 'cost should decrease monotonically' may not happen. In that case, we need to try another technique. Please look at **new_X**. Replacing **X** to **new_X** make convergence easier.